# Why do I get different running time each time I solve my model?

Tags: python, time, gurobi

I have a simple BQP model coded in python and solved by gurobi. But each time I run it, although the solution and obj value are the same, the running time varies even up to 25% in some instances. I also have a simple LP model which results in the same problem. I checked out the time with both models. Runtime and time.time() and both of them change in iterations of running the code for each specific instance. When I check the gurobi log, I see the logs are quite different each time I run the model. I wonder if I need to fix something to get a consistent running time. It should be pointed out that I have the same problem (either running on my computer or on a shared cluster).

I've shared a link to the log file here : [log file](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1ZeDz1yuban-7QMdcS-7eEBz08ynNwQQW/view?usp=sharing).

Your assistance is much appreciated.

Comment: Please post the logs to illustrate.

Comment: I have added the logs of running an instance twice

Answer (score 0):

Gurobi is behaving exactly the same in both runs:

```
Run 1:
Cutting planes:
  Gomory: 4
  MIR: 13
  Flow cover: 279
  RLT: 168
  BQP: 165

Explored 291452 nodes (10662765 simplex iterations) in 722.77 seconds

Run 2:
Cutting planes:
  Gomory: 4
  MIR: 13
  Flow cover: 279
  RLT: 168
  BQP: 165

Explored 291452 nodes (10662765 simplex iterations) in 541.59 seconds
```

That you see a different run time is most likely due to other tasks consuming CPU and memory resources a the same time. To get comparable results, you need to run on a machine that is not doing anything else at the time of solving. For instance, using a laptop to do such an experiment is not going to give you reliable results. There are also things like thermal throttling that might interfere with precise time measurements.

One possible solution to this is to run the same experiment multiple times and then compare min or mean of the run times. In any case, running this on a dedicated computing server is the best option.

See also the answer to the question in the [Gurobi community forum](https://support.gurobi.com/hc/en-us/community/posts/360072839192-Python-Running-time-Why-do-I-get-different-running-time-each-time-I-solve-my-model-).

Comment: Thanks for your answer. That is true. Gurobi behaves exactly the same, but if you compare the gap percentage from the very beginning (from the 10th sec), it is different in 2logs. I wanted to see if it is normal, since I have not found many people encountering this problem. I though maybe I have to fix something in my code or there is a better method to compute accurate time. Anyway, it seems that running the same experiment multiple times is the best option.